# Open field in protected, shared Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a shared, protected workbook that has a button to bring up a search form. There are two fields on this form, txtYear and cbxRegion, that I need enabled. Whenever I try to open the fields, it works until I exit Excel.

I have tried unprotecting the workbook, unsharing it, and commenting out any reference in the VBA to reprotecting the form. And still, even the edited VBA reverts back to the original.

This is the section of code referring to the form I need enabled. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Excel 2010.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim strDb As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim row As Integer
Dim AccessVersionID As String

cbxRegion.Value = Worksheets("Parameters").Cells(5, 14)
Me.txtYear = Worksheets("Parameters").Cells(4, 7)
Me.chkBoth = Worksheets("Parameters").Cells(9, 2)
Me.chkConsultant = Worksheets("Parameters").Cells(7, 2)
Me.chkInHouse = Worksheets("Parameters").Cells(8, 2)
'Set region values
'Open connection
'Select Case SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessVer)
'Case 11: AccessVersionID = "2003"
'End Select

'If AccessVersionID = "2003" Then
'    strDb = Worksheets("Parameters").Cells(17, 2).Value 'This will reference the path
'Else
    strDb = Worksheets("Parameters").Cells(18, 2).Value
'End If

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strDb & ";"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'Get recordset
With rs
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Open "Select * From LookupRegion"
    .Requery
End With

'Add regions
row = 0
With rs
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
        cbxRegion.AddItem ![region]
        cbxRegion.list(row, 1) = ![RegionName]
        row = row + 1
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

'Close the recordset
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. In order, I:

- Unshared the workbook
- Unprotected the workbook
- Saved, closed, and reopened the workbook to make sure the settings stayed
- Enabled the fields
- Saved, closed, and reopened the workbook to make sure the settings stayed
- Protected the workbook
- Shared the workbook (as required by the specifications I was given, I would rather not share it but it really isn't my call here)
- Saved, closed, and reopened the workbook to make sure the settings stayed

And now it works exactly as I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, the best advice anyone can give you for a shared workbook is: don't use them.

Shared Workbooks are impossible to troubleshoot. Their aberrant behaviour cannot be fixed. They don't follow any logic. Once a shared workbook starts acting up and behaving strangely, you have reached the inevitable end stage. Nothing can be done to fix it. The behaviour is not necessarily reproducible.

If you need simultaneous multi-user write access to a dataset, then Excel is the wrong tool. Use a database.

Don't use shared workbooks.

Comment: While I appreciate the advice,  this doesnt get me any closer to a solution,  since I still have the problem even after unsharing the workbook.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. It is impossible to troubleshoot a shared workbook that shows problems of any kind. That is the main problem and the reason not to use shared workbooks. Your file is corrupt. And it will remain corrupt, regardless of whether you now un-share it or not. You won't be able to repair it. Salvage the data and build a new solution. If you have learned something from this experience, you may prefer to build a solution that does not involve shared workbooks.

Comment: Actually I did manage to fix it, quite easily. It just had to be done in a specific order and it works perfectly now, and does what I need it to do.